# Post answer in comments on check of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make my code in a way so that once you check the right radio button(yes/no) that along with the question shows up in the `textarea`. If the `yes` radio button is checked.. I want `yes` to show up in the `textarea` with the right question like `Question 1`, If `no` radio button is checked, I want `no` to show up in the `textarea`. Here is what I have right now:

HTML:

```
Question 1 Yes<input id='chk1' value="yes" type='radio' />No<input name='chk3' value="no" type='checkbox' /><br />
Question 2 Yes<input id='chk2' value="yes" type='radio' />No<input name='chk3' value="no" type='checkbox' /><br />
Question 3 Yes<input id='chk3' value="yes" type='radio' />No<input name='chk3' value="no" type='checkbox' /><br />
Other comments<textarea id='comment'></textarea><br /><input type=submit name=submit value='Post' />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#chk1').change(function(){
    $('#comment').text("Question 1:" + "");
});
$('#chk2').change(function(){
    $('#comment').text("Question 1:" + "");
});
$('#chk3').change(function(){
    $('#comment').text("Question 1:" + "");
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gk05pkkh/3/

Comment: What's exactly the question here ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if the yes checkbox is checked.. I want yes to show up in the textarea with the right question like Question 1, If no checkbox is checked, I want no to show up in the textarea

Comment: Shouldn't those be radio buttons instead of checkboxes? Otherwise what's stopping someone from checking yes *and* no for a question?

Comment: you probably need radiobuttons instead of a checkbox

Comment: @j08691 correct, updated question

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/gk05pkkh/7/

Comment: @Sushil very close. I want to get all answers on the textarea at the same time though... like if question 2 is checked i want question 1 to remain there with its value and add question 2 underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using "name" not "id" on your inputs so they can be shared.

HTML:

```
Question 1 Yes<input name='chk1' value="yes" type='radio' />No<input name='chk1' value="no" type='radio' /><br />
Question 2 Yes<input name='chk2' value="yes" type='radio' />No<input name='chk2' value="no" type='radio' /><br />
Question 3 Yes<input name='chk3' value="yes" type='radio' />No<input name='chk3' value="no" type='radio' /><br />
Other comments<textarea id='comment'></textarea><br /><input type=submit name=submit value='Post' />
```

JQuery:

```
$('input[name="chk1"]').change(function(){
    checkQuestion("Question 1", this.value);
});
$('input[name="chk2"]').change(function(){
    checkQuestion("Question 2", this.value);
});
$('input[name="chk3"]').change(function(){
    checkQuestion("Question 3", this.value);
});

function checkQuestion(text, value) {
    if ($('#comment').text().indexOf(text)<0)
        $('#comment').text($('#comment').text() + text + ":" + value + "\n");
    else {
        var oldValue = 'yes';
        if (value==='yes') oldValue = 'no';
        $('#comment').text($('#comment').text().replace(text + ":" + oldValue, text + ":" + value));
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gk05pkkh/24/

Comment: very close. I want to get all answers on the textarea at the same time though... like if question 2 is checked i want question 1 to remain there with its value and add question 2 underneath

Comment: Updated and cleaned up with a function call to prevent repeated code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not pulling the value of the checkbox when you set the code to put anything inside #comment.  Change this:

```
$('#chk1').change(function(){
    $('#comment').text("Question 1:" + "");
});
```

to this:

```
$('#chk1').change(function(){
    var response = $(this).val();
    $('#comment').text("Question 1:" + response);
});
```

And use radio buttons, as stated in other comments here.

Comment: Solves 25% of my problem... I still can't get `no` to show up in the textarea and also the right question

Answer (score 1):

I took some liberties with what I think you are trying to do. For this HTML:

```
<div class="questionWrap">
    <span class="question">Question 1:</span>
    <label>Yes
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Yes"/>
    </label>
    <label>No
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="No"/>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="questionWrap">
    <span class="question">Question 2:</span>
    <label>Yes
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Yes"/>
    </label>
    <label>No
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="No"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

This JS:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
   var parent = $(this).closest('.questionWrap'),
       text = parent.find('.question').text(),
       answer = parent.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val(),
       answerStr = '';

    parent.attr('data-question', text  + answer);

    $('[data-question]').each(function(ind, ele){
        answerStr += ( $(ele).attr('data-question') +'\n');
    });

    $('textarea').text(answerStr);


});
```

[**See this functioning fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gk05pkkh/25/)

Comment: very close. I want to get all answers on the textarea at the same time though... like if question 2 is checked i want question 1 to remain there with its value and add question 2 underneath

Comment: @user4756836 I updated the fiddle and answer to reflect